# jquery ajax call returning error

Tags: jquery

Can't able to figure out, why this jquery function always returns an error instead of success.

So I hope to get some feedback ;-)

Thanks in advance!

Bas

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url : '/ajax_push_order_status_request.php',           
        data: dataString,
        success:function (data) {
                $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
                $(".success").append(data);
            },

         error: function (data) {
                alert( "ERROR:  " + data );
                $('.error1').fadeIn(1000);
            }


    });
```

My PHP script returns:

```
{"result":true}
```

Comment: Post your PHP code here.

Comment: if you go in your browser to:   http://www.zwembad.eu/ajax_push_order_status_request.php   You can see it is returning "result":true   but in the ajax call you are getting some type of security not allowed error

Comment: @w3bMak3r we could go to the url, but this *really* should be part of the question (I'm betting that url will go away before SO :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call is to a different domain (the site is on `zwembad.eu` while the ajax call goes to `www.zwembad.eu`). You'll need to use jsonp instead of json and set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header correctly, or make sure you make the ajax call on the same domain.

Comment: OMG! cannot believe that I have overlooked this, shame ;-)
Thanks a lot thebjorn an everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure the `url` is in right path.

```
 url : 'ajax_push_order_status_request.php',    // use this if it is same dir
```

Answer (score 0):

It`s a cross domain error.
If you run the js code on crome console you can see the error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.zwembad.eu/ajax_push_order_status_request.php. Origin http://zwembad.eu is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.